# How to fix balance factor of avl tree after inserting elements?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I will be providing my C code where I implemented an AVL tree. For some test cases, the code works normally where it displays the balance factor for each element when the bst gets traversed. In one of the test cases that I had the balance factor exceeded (-1,0,1). I was not exactly sure what went wrong. I'm not able to understand if I returned the wrong values in the NODE* leftRotate, rightRotate and Insert functions.

I would also like to get clarified with leftRotate and rightRotate functions. We are passing the root node as the parameters in the function. If we consider the leftRotate function here

```
NODE* leftRotate(NODE* x){
    NODE* y = x->right;
    NODE* T2 = y->left;
    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;
    int x_height = max(height(x->left),height(x->right)+1);
    int y_height = max(height(y->left),height(y->right) + 1);
    return y;
}
```

when they write

```
NODE* y = x->right;
NODE* T2 = y->left;
```

we get our tree something like this:

```
x
 \ R
  y
 / L
T2
```

here are we getting an RL case so we should apply RR first

```
x
 \R
  y
   \R
    T2
```

The answer will be

```
 y
/ \
x  T2
```

What I'm unsure in the leftrotate function we are just rotating the root element left instead applying the usual RL technique. I just wanted to clarify if thats all we should be doing over applying the RL,RR case for it.

```
//Avl tree 

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *left,*right;
} NODE;

NODE* createNode(int ele){
    NODE* newnode = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    newnode->data = ele;
    newnode->right = newnode->left = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

NODE* createBT(){
    int ele;
    printf("Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):\n");
    scanf("%d",&ele);

    if (ele == -1){
        return NULL;
    }

    NODE* newnode = createNode(ele);
    printf("Enter the left child of %d(-1 to stop),\n",ele);
    newnode->left = createBT();
    printf("Enter the right child of %d(-1 to stop),\n",ele);
    newnode->right = createBT();
    return newnode;
}

int max(int a, int b){
    if (a > b)
        return a;
    else 
        return b; 
}

int height(NODE* root){
    if (root == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return max(height(root->left),height(root->right)) + 1;
}

int BalFactor(NODE* temp){
    if (temp == NULL){
        printf("Tree is empty\n");
    }
    return height(temp->left) - height(temp->right);
}


//note: The NODE* x is the root element
//Visualise anticlockwise rotation on the root don't think of RL case
NODE* leftRotate(NODE* x){
    NODE* y = x->right;
    NODE* T2 = y->left;
    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;
    int x_height = max(height(x->left),height(x->right)+1);
    int y_height = max(height(y->left),height(y->right) + 1);
    return y;
}

//note:NODE* y is the root element
NODE* rightRotate(NODE* y){
    NODE* x = y->left;
    NODE* T2 = x->right;
    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;
    int x_height = max(height(x->left),height(x->right)) + 1;
    int y_height = max(height(y->left),height(y->right)) + 1;
    return x; 
}

//Recursive insert
/*
NODE* insert(NODE* root, int ele){
    if (root == NULL){
        return createNode(ele);
    }

    else if(ele > root->data){
        root->right = insert(root->right,ele);    
    }

    else if(ele < root->data){
        root->left = insert(root->left,ele);    
    }

    else
        return root;
    
    int h = 1 + max(height(root->left),height(root->right));
    int bal = BalFactor(root); 
    
    //balance factor is greater than 1 its either LL or LR 
    //balance factor is lesss than -1  its either RR ot RL

    //LL
    if (bal > 1 && ele < root->left->data){
        return rightRotate(root);
    }
    //RR
    
    if (bal > -1 && ele > root->right->data){
        return leftRotate(root);
    }
    //LR
    if (bal > 1 && ele > root->right->data){
        root->left = leftRotate(root->left);
        return rightRotate(root);
    }
    //RL
    if (bal < -1 && ele < root->right->data){
        return leftRotate(root);
    }
    return root;
}
*/

//iterative insert function
NODE* insert(NODE* root,int ele){
    NODE* newnode = createNode(ele);
    NODE* x = root;
    NODE* y = NULL;

    while (x != NULL){
        y = x;
        if (ele < x->data)
            x = x->left;
        else
            x = x->right;
    }

    if(y == NULL)
        y = newnode;
    
    else if(ele < y->data)
        y->left = newnode;
    
    else 
        y->right = newnode;

    return y;

    int h = 1 + max(height(y->left),height(y->right));
    int bal = BalFactor(y); 
    //LL
    //balance factor is greater than 1 its either LL or LR 
    //balance factor is lesss than -1  its either RR ot RL
    if (bal > 1 && ele < y->left->data){
        return rightRotate(y);
    }
    //RR
    
    if (bal > -1 && ele > y->right->data){
        return leftRotate(y);
    }
    //LR
    if (bal > 1 && ele > y->right->data){
        y->left = leftRotate(y->left);
        return rightRotate(y);
    }
    //RL
    if (bal < -1 && ele < y->right->data){
        return leftRotate(y);
    }
    return root;
}

void inorder(NODE* root){
    if (root != NULL){
        inorder(root->left);
        printf(" %d (%d)", root->data, BalFactor(root));
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}
 
void postorder(NODE* root){
    if (root != NULL){
        postorder(root->left);
        postorder(root->right);
        printf(" %d (%d)", root->data, BalFactor(root));
    }
}

void preorder(NODE* root){
    if (root != NULL){
        printf(" %d (%d)", root->data, BalFactor(root));
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}


int main(){
    NODE* root  = NULL;
    root = createBT();
    int ch,ele;
    printf("\nList of operations:\n1.Insert\n2.Traversals and display balance factor\n3.Exit\n");
    while(1){
        printf("\nEnter your choice:\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);

        if (ch == 1){
            printf("Enter the element to insert:\n");
            scanf("%d",&ele);
            insert(root,ele);
        }

        else if(ch == 2){
            printf("Inorder traversal:\n");
            inorder(root);
            
            printf("\nPreorder traversal:\n");
            preorder(root);
            
            printf("\nPostorder traversal:\n");
            postorder(root);
        }

        else if(ch == 3){
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("Enter a valid choice\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the code:

```
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
10
Enter the left child of 10(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
9
Enter the left child of 9(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
8
Enter the left child of 8(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
7
Enter the left child of 7(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
-1
Enter the right child of 7(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
12
Enter the left child of 12(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
-1
Enter the right child of 12(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
-1
Enter the right child of 8(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
13
Enter the left child of 13(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
-1
Enter the right child of 13(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
-1
Enter the right child of 9(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
20
Enter the left child of 20(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
-1
Enter the right child of 20(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
-1
Enter the right child of 10(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
21
Enter the left child of 21(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
-1
Enter the right child of 21(-1 to stop),
Enter the element(Don't enter any duplicates):
-1

 10 (1) 9 (2) 8 (1) 7 (-1) 12 (0) 13 (0) 20 (0) 21 (-2) 30 (-1) 40 (0)
Postorder traversal:
 12 (0) 7 (-1) 13 (0) 8 (1) 20 (0) 9 (2) 40 (0) 30 (-1) 21 (-2) 10 (1)
Enter your choice:
3
```

Comment: In `leftRotate()`, code calculates `x_height` , but does not later use  `x_height`.  Why do that calculation?

Comment: An AVL tree does not call `height` to rebalance. Instead it should store the balance factor in its nodes and derive from other balance factors how it should be updated during a rotation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think I realized the flaw with my approach. I have to include height in my typedef struct

Comment: @dev0419 For an AVL tree, a balance factor [-1,0, 1] is needed per node.

Comment: @dev0419 Aside: Improve and simplify: `newnode = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));` --> `newnode = malloc(sizeof newnode[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

When you implement an AVL tree, make sure that you keep a height member so that you can check if a height is +/- 2. Then, as you insert, you would rebalance if the height of any node becomes > 2 or < -2.

The only way to make sure that you're entering the right values is to input them into your program and then do an inorder, preorder, postorder print of the tree. Use your program's output of the prints and rebuild your tree on paper to make sure that the tree forms properly and that your rebalancing functions are working.

The [AVL Tree Visualizer Website](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/AVLtree.html) by University of San Francisco has a great visualizer that allows you to see the rotations on an AVL tree that you can use to help you understand how the rotations work.

The rotations will always be the same no matter how an AVL tree is implemented. [Here is a detailed explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Rebalancing) of how the RL technique works. There are many other less technical explanations online that may be easier to understand.